# Language Locale Codes: Is BCP 47 being adopted now?

Tags: java, android, ios, localization, locale

My curiosity is from the underscores vs hyphens (en-GB Vs en_GB) being used for the locale codes.

- Is BCP 47 the standard widely considered this?
- I see underscores being used more often. However, I do see a shift towards hyphens.

  - Java 7 uses [underscores](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html).
  - However, Java 8 uses [hyphens](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html).
  - [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html) and [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) use underscores. Should we expect a shift to hyphens in iOS and Android in the future? Maybe the answer is 'yes' for Android as it's tied to Java.

Comment: There is a GEP over this issue for Java 8: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/128.